# Android migrate upload key

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-console

I'm migrating my app to a new version. I have decided to start from blank and completely rewrite it. 
I created new project in android studio but kept the original applicationId and all other names because I want to replace my original app in play store with.

I was using this config in my app build.gradle for upload key.

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        def credsFilePath = file("../../../keys/keyInfo.json").toString()
        def credsFile = new File(credsFilePath, "").getText('UTF-8')
        def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(credsFile)
        storeFile file(json.android.storeFile)
        storePassword = json.android.storePassword
        keyAlias = json.android.keyAlias
        keyPassword = json.android.keyPassword
    }
}
```

But for some reason when I try to upload my new app bundle do dev console it says: 
Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again: SHA1: *****.

[image: androiddevconsoleerror]

I thought that i'm using the same upload key so there should not be any problems.

Comment: Were you uploading an App Bundle in your previous project as well? How are you generating the App Bundle: gradle command line? Studio's Generate release AAB?)? Also, we don't know what is in that keyInfo.json: is it an absolute path or a relative path? If a relative path, you could be pointing at a different key named the same. Did you reinstall Studio? If so, another debug keystore could have been created with the same file path.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a problem when you have a different database file. I think that you are not connected with your original database file. When you are trying to migrate or update your app to a new version or come back to the an odd version you should have the same SHA1.

Comment: But i'm signing both versions with the same key right. Why dev console says it is different.

Comment: @rendom Did you changed during anything during setting up your database?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in build.gradle setting

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug <--- needs signingConfigs.release
```